# how to call a java class from OnItemClick()?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-intent

I have a problem to call a java class from OnItemClickListener widget..

```
  private OnItemClickListener detailClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent productDetailsIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MenuRestaurantActivity.class);
                startActivity(productDetailsIntent);
    }
        };
```

Parameter in currentActivity isn't send to anotherActivity class..

How to fix it?

thanks for your attention..

Comment: what type of problem are you getting?

Comment: i have a problem to call another java class, and it's also parameter in CurrentActivity, it can't send to another java class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this in your onclick

```
productDetailsIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MenuRestaurantActivity.class);
```

use this line

```
Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In FirstActivity.java file onclick button you should use below code.

```
    Intent i1 = new Intent(firstactivity.this, secondactivity.class);
    i1.putExtra("type", "edit");
   startActivity(i1);
```

In secondActivity.java file oncreate .. use this code.

```
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     Strinjg Value = extras.getSerializable("type").toString();
```

Comment: thanks..
But the parameter in currentActivity isn't send to NextActivity class, I have try this code

Comment: thanks for your help.. How about parameter in currentActivity? Can it send to another class?

Answer (score 1):

you must declare following lines in your AndroidManifest.xml file, otherwise it will generate an error.

```
<activity android:name=".MenuRestaurantActivity"  android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Comment: thanks for your help..
How about parameter in currentActivity? Can it send to another class?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private OnItemClickListener detailClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) { 
         Intent productDetailsIntent = new Intent(ActivityName.this,MenuRestaurantActivity.class);
         startActivity(productDetailsIntent);
     }
 };
```

Comment: thanks for your help.. How about parameter in currentActivity? Can it send to another class?

Comment: Yes.you can receive it as a context